# MISRA C 2012 Rule 16.1 All switch statements should be well formed

Tags: c, misra

I am trying to get rid of violation og rule 16.1 from my code.

Sample code:

```
switch (cmd) {
    case ADD:
        result = add(op1, op2);
        break;
    case SUB: 
        if (!flag) {    // Problem here!
            break;     
        }
        //Fallthrough
    case ALU_CMD_SUB:
        result = sub(op1, op2);
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        break;
    case ALU_CMD_DIV:
        result = divide(op1, op2);
        break;
    case ALU_CMD_EXP:
        result = (int32_t)expo((uint32_t)op1, (uint32_t)op2);
        break;
    default:
        incr_default(&default_cond);
        //fix for the violation: insert a break statement
        break;
}
```

Here the switch case with SUB is not well formed.

Is there any way to fix this issue without having much noise in the code.

This is also violating rule 16.3 where switch case doesn't have a break statement.

Comment: I don't have a copy of MISRA C. What is Rule 16.1 - and is it a directive or a rule?

Comment: @AJD: Rule 16.1 is rather elaborate — it rewrites the permissible syntax for `switch` statements.  Rule 16.3 is simpler: "An unconditional `break` shall terminate each _switch-clause_", where _switch-clause_ is one of the terms used in the rewritten switch syntax — basically, it's a non-empty sequence of `case` labels (or possibly a `default` clause) plus the action following that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly trivial to fix:

```
case SUB: 
   SUB_stuff();
   ALU_CMD_SUB_stuff();
   break;

case ALU_CMD_SUB:
   ALU_CMD_SUB_stuff();
   break;
```

Let the compiler worry about how to translate the above to machine code with a minimum amount of branches.

These are very sound MISRA rules, as the presence of a "case fall-through" is very dangerous and almost always the result either from forgetting `break` by accident or from a poor underlying design. I used to be a fan of "case fall-through" once, but eventually realised that the need for using such fall-throughs originates from muddy thinking elsewhere in the program.

Similarly, using it for code optimization purposes (such as "Duff's Device") is a thing of the 1980s and nowadays nothing but pre-mature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

In context, meeting the letter of the MISRA law (Rule 16.3), you could consider:

```
switch (cmd) {
    case ADD:
        result = add(op1, op2);
        break;
    case SUB: 
    case ALU_CMD_SUB:
        if (cmd == SUB && !flag) {
            break;     
        }
        result = sub(op1, op2);
        .
        .
        .    
        break;
    …
}
```

or perhaps:

```
switch (cmd) {
    case ADD:
        result = add(op1, op2);
        break;
    case SUB: 
    case ALU_CMD_SUB:
        if (cmd == ALU_CMD_SUB || flag) {
            result = sub(op1, op2);
            .
            .
            .
        }
        break;
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to the question, if indeed the fallthrough is deliberate, is to raise a Deviation.

Attempts to circumvent the Rule, by trying to write clever code, makes things less clear, and less maintainable - a Deviation makes it clear what you are wanting to do, and means future maintainers do not make mistakes.

As an aside, it is proposed, for the next edition of the C standard, to add an annotation `[[fallthrough]]` to convey that this is the expected behaviour!  I am pretty sure MISRA C will recognize this attribute promptly after publication, and Rule 16.3 updated...

Answer (score -2):

Fall through is a valid construct in C - it can improve code efficiency. One of the joys of having a lot of experience is knowing when it is alright to break 'rules'. In this case, where good engineering and code safety is important (*), document why this rule has been broken at this point.

I am assuming in this case that the `if !flag` element should not be checked under `ALU_CMD_SUB`, and that the `SUB` element is a valid precursor to doing the `ALU_CMD_SUB` element.

(*) The adoption of MISRA implies a heightened requirement for code safety.

Comment: For the downvoter. Deviation from MISRA is permissible as long as it is well documented - what rule is broken and the reason for deviation.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but you don't mention the deviation rules in the answer, and the question wasn't asking how to write a deviation but how to fix the code so that a deviation isn't needed.  There are numerous rules in MISRA that I'm relieved I don't have to pay attention to — because I don't work on systems where MISRA rules are required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Semantics, but one way to fix the issue is to acknowledge the deviation (although I didn't mention it explicitly). I don't use MISRA myself, but I have worked with other technical regulatory systems.